# Iterating thro' a set of addresses - Geocoder Service

Tags: geocoding

I have a set of addresses in string format. I need to get the lat/long position information for each of those addresses using Geocoder service. Unfortunately, iterating thro' the set of addresses is not giving me the expected result in the registered callback.

Is there is a better way to get the lat/long info of the address set?

My question is similar to :
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/forum.html?place=topic%2Fgoogle-maps-js-api-v3%2F4l6BkdzmHOo%2Fdiscussion

TIA for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer that worked for me:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlgeocode.html#samplecode

Thanks.